# Map HTTP POST parameter to Dictionary<string, string[]>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a problem with parameter mapping for an ASP.NET MVC action. I post data similar to this from the browser:

```
{
   "query" : "some search phrase",
   "faceting" : {
      "colors" : ["red", "blue"],
      "brands" : ["Fantastic"]
}
```

This what the action method signature looks like:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> External(string query, Dictionary<string, string[]> faceting, int page = 1)
```

The expected outcome is a dictionary with to keys, "colors" and "brands", but instead I got three keys: "colors[0]", "colors[1]", and "brands[0]", with arrays with one element each.

I cannot change the action method signature to

```
public async Task<JsonResult> External(string query, colors string[], brands string[], faceting, int page = 1)
```

because the faceting is dynamic and I don't now what keys to receive. The client could post neither one of the to given examples, or add more keys, that I don't know of when writing the code.

Any idea how to fix the mapping, or any other construct instead of Dictionary that would work better?

Comment: In order to bind, your data would need to be in the format - `faceting[0].Key: 'colors', faceting[0].Value[0]: 'red', faceting[0].Value[1]: 'blue', faceting[1].Key: 'brands', faceting[1].Value[0]: 'Fantastic'`. But that also depends on how your are sending it (are you using `JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: 'application/json`?)

Comment: The data is POSTed from the client (javascript/angularJS in a browser). Creating data looking like you're suggestion would be doable, but I think it would not be so pretty. Today I have this little helper method:
    var addFacetToSearch = function (facet, facetValue) {
        $scope.request.faceting[facet] = $scope.request.faceting[facet] || [];
        $scope.request.faceting[facet].push(facetValue);
    }

($scope.request is the JSON object I later post to the server.

Comment: Unfortunately the `DefaultModelBinder` does not work well with dictionaries (it will work where both the key and value are simple types - e.g. `Dictionary<string, string>` but not when the value is a complex type.

Comment: Creating your own binder is relatively easy, check [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/payloads-as-dynamic-objects-in-asp-net-mvc) that shows how to add model binding support for dynamic types. BTW, a dynamic object could be a good replacement for this dictionary. You'd get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the design a little. The action method signature now looks like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> External(string query, Facet[] faceting, int page = 1)
```

and the Facet class like this:

```
public class Facet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If I have two colors I simply submit two Facet objects with Name = "colors".

I then have to process the facets in a different way than I first was planning to do, but this approach is simpler than creating my own model binder or handling the JSON data myself.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
async Task<JObject> GetJObjectFromFormData()
    {
        using (Stream strea = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            await Request.InputStream.CopyToAsync(strea);
            strea.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strea))
            {
                var req = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req) ? JObject.Parse(req) : null;

            }
        }
    }
```

method accept from url that p parameter.

```
async Task<JsonResult> External(int p)
    {
        var formData = await GetJObjectFromFormData();
        if (formData == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("form data");
        string query = formData["query"].ToObject<string>();
        Debug.WriteLine("query : " + query);
        Dictionary<string, string[]> faceting = formData["faceting"]
            .ToDictionary<JToken, string, string[]>(
            (j) =>
            {
                return ((JProperty)j).Name;
            },
            (j) =>
            {
                return j.First.ToObject<string[]>();
            });
        foreach (var key in faceting.Keys)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("key : {0}, values : {1}", key, string.Join(",", faceting[key]));
        }
        return Json("");

    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC already offers a mechanism to create your own model binder. No need to reparse the already parsed data